Excel How to remove Message Box from code
This code (from Jon Peltier) lets you select a range for the series name.
Is there a way to make this work without the Message Box?
To say e.g. Set SeriesNameRange = ("C27:E27")?
Sub SelectRangeWithSeriesNames()
   If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation, "No Chart Selected"
   Else
     Dim Prompt As String
     Prompt = "Select a range that contains series names for the active chart."
     Dim Title As String
     Title = "Select Series Names"

     Dim SeriesNameRange As Range
     On Error Resume Next
     Set SeriesNameRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt, Title, , , , , , 8)
     On Error GoTo 0
     
     If Not SeriesNameRange Is Nothing Then
       If SeriesNameRange.Rows.Count = 1 Or SeriesNameRange.Columns.Count = 1 Then
         With ActiveChart
           Dim iSrs As Long
           For iSrs = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
             If iSrs <= SeriesNameRange.Cells.Count Then
               .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Name = _
                   "=" & SeriesNameRange.Cells(iSrs).Address(, , , True)
             End If
           Next
         End With
       Else
         MsgBox "Select a range with one row or one column", vbExclamation, _
             "Must be One Row or Column"
       End If
     End If
   End If
 End Sub

This is what I tried, but it's not working:
Sub SelectRangeWithSeriesNames()

Dim SeriesNameRange As Range

Set SeriesNameRange = Range("B1:C1")

  With ActiveChart
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = SeriesNameRange

End Sub

This is the "unedited" code to create the chart:
Sub Chart_001()
    Dim objChart As ChartObject
    Dim myChtRange As Range
    Dim myDataRange As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set myChtRange = .Range("G25:J35")
        Set myDataRange = .Range("G22:J23") 
        Set objChart = .ChartObjects.Add( _
            Left:=myChtRange.Left, Top:=myChtRange.Top, _
            Width:=myChtRange.Width, Height:=myChtRange.Height)
        With objChart.Chart
            .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData Source:=myDataRange
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("G21")
            .Parent.Name = Range("G21")
        End With
    End With
End Sub

I've tried to put the two together, without any actual idea how. I just starting to use VBA recently, still learning the basics. Thank you for any help.

Set SeriesNameRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C27:E27")?

@user23636411 please edit your post to show what you tried; one cannot readily read code in a comment. (put an update AFTER your initial question)

@user23636411 The code from @BigBen answered your question how to remove MessageBox. But you still need the For loop if SeriesNameRange is multiple cells range.
